# Doubt in the Second fundamental form of a immersed manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $f \colon M^{n} \rightarrow \overline{M}^{n+m}$ be an immersion. Identifying $TpM$ with $Im(df_{p})$, we have the following decomposition

$$T_{p}\overline{M} = T_{p}M \oplus (T_{p}M)^{\perp}$$

Consider $X, Y$ two tangent vector fields in $M$ and $\overline{X}, \overline{Y}$ some extensions to $\overline{M}$, define

$$B(X,Y) = \overline{\nabla}_{\overline{X}} \overline{Y} - (\overline{\nabla}_{\overline{X}} \overline{Y})^{T}.$$

**Here's my doubt**: Do Carmo's book affirms that $B(X,Y)p$ only depends on $X_p$ and $Y_p$.
Apparently this comes immediately from the bilinearity and symmetry of $B$. I can't understand this.

**My thoughts:** In general, we know that $(\nabla_X Y)p$ only depends on the value of $X$ and $Y$ in $p$ and $Y$ along a curve which passes through $p$ with velocity $X_p$. It seems the fact that $B(X,Y)$ lies on $(T_pM)^{\perp}$ "kills" the dependence of $Y$ along a curve passing through $p$ with velocity $X_p$ and it only remains the dependent with $X_p$ and $Y_p$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The fact that $B$ is symmetric comes from the fact that $M$ is immersed so that its tangent bundle is closed under the Lie bracket. By its definition, $B$ is tensorial in the first entry, and by symmetry, it is then tensorial in the second entry.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference with the definition of a form to be tensorial ?

Comment: Usually we say that something is tensorial if it is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-linear

Comment: I still don't understand how to conclude that $B(X,Y)p$ only depends on $X_p$ and $Y_p$.

Comment: Suppose that $Y_1(p) = Y_2(p)$. Then $B(X,Y_1)(p) - B(X,Y_2)(p) = B(X,Y_1-Y_2)(p) = B(Y_1-Y_2,X)(p) = 0$ since $(Y_1-Y_2)(p)=0$ and $B(U,V)(p)$ only depends on $U(p)$ in the first variable.

Comment: Thank you very much!